# A phone call with my travel agent

Tags: lateral-thinking, geography

"Hi Pat, I just got the itinerary you sent over. Are you actually drinking at work?"

"Nolo contendre. But what's the problem?"

"It doesn't make any sense. I mean, one of the lines is repeated, and there are seven separate destinations. I don't even know where some of these places are!"

"What do you mean? There's only one destination."

"Nuevo Laredo! Diego Garcia! Vicksburg! How do you think I can afford all that?"

"You didn't think you were GOING to any of those places, did you? Call me when you figure it out."

---

Pat is so infuriating! This is the itinerary Pat sent me:

- River rafting in Nuevo Laredo
- Clothes shopping in Diego Garcia
- Music festival in Vicksburg
- Sport driving in Milan
- Bird watching at the seashore by Corpus Christi
- Bird watching at the seashore by Corpus Christi
- Observe parliament in Freetown
- Dancing in Buenos Aires

Can you help me figure out where Pat wants to send me this time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I got it!

The answer is:

> Budapest

And here's why:

> It's all to do with the **military alphabet**. Letter by letter:

> B: Nuevo Laredo is on the (in Spanish) Rio **Bravo**

> U: Diego Garcia is a military base, so **Uniform**

> D: Riverfest in Vicksburg is in the Mississippi **Delta**

> A: The car company Alfa (**Alpha**) Romeo is in Milan

> P: Padre (**Papa**) Island National Seashore is in Corpus Christi

> E: **Echo** Park is a birding hotspot in Corpus Christi (Edit to amend that actually it's because this is **Echo**ed from the previous letter.)

> S: Freetown is in **Sierra** Leone

> T: The main dance in Buenos Aires is **Tango**!

Comment: Awesome job! Right in almost every detail. There is an easier explanation for the sixth letter, though...

Comment: OH, hah, is it because rot13(gur ercrngrq vgrz vf na rpub)??

Comment: Yep! That is correct :-)

Comment: Nice Kristin!!!