# My friend's scrapbook

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, geography

I was visiting with my friend Susie the other day when we got talking about our travels. As we discussed favorite cities we had been to, she suddenly got up and went to grab a dusty scrapbook from the attic. She turned to a page and said it was some souvenirs for a world tour of cities she'd done over the years, starting almost 20 years ago.

Looking at the page, however, some of the scraps made no sense, and turns out, this isn't some straightforward scrapbook. Apparently her (slightly crazy) travel agent Pat had helped her put together the scrapbook.

---

On the page were:

1. An old comic strip of some people in an office.
2. Betting stubs from New York, seems she hit a trifecta!
3. Medical photos of her feet!? Gross.
4. A well-worn music festival bracelet with the Spanish flag on it.
5. Her tour itinerary for a trip London, seems she went to the Olympics and parliament.

Can you help me figure out what cities Susie visited on her tour?

<sub><sup>Thanks Jeremy Dover and [lovely Pat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99827/a-phone-call-with-my-travel-agent) for the inspiration for my first puzzle</sup></sub>

Comment: Given 3) above, I’m guessing New York (city) and London aren’t actually the cities she visited, but are more cryptic?

Comment: About time for a hint? Still interested!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here is my attempt to so far.

1. An old comic strip of some people in an office.

> I believe this is a reference to the comic strip *Dilbert*, which usually takes place in an office environment. According to the Wikipedia page, the workplace location is Silicon Valley. So I'm guessing the city was San Jose, the largest city in Silicon Valley.

2. Betting stubs from New York, seems she hit a trifecta!

> I am not familiar with American laws on betting, but it seems betting is severely restricted in New York City. Given the stubs may be as old as 20 years, this complicates things further.  However, some further research suggests that there are many cities named New York, not just in America (https://geotargit.com/called.php?qcity=New%20York). Sadly, I don't know enough about gambling or races which may result in a trifecta (I'm guessing it is horse or greyhound racing) to determine which city this may be.

3. Medical photos of her feet!? Gross.

> Reasons for taking photos of one's feet may be to seek medical advice on conditions such as burns (from firewalking, desert sand, etc.), frostbite, insect bites, etc. (This actually happened to me in Asia when I was bitten more than 20 times on my feet by an unknown insect).  Unfortunately, the list of possibilities does not let me narrow this down to a particular continent, let alone city.

4. A well-worn music festival bracelet with the Spanish flag on it.

> I think the festival in question may be the *Monegros Desert Festival*, the nearest city being Zaragoza (followed by Barcelona).

5. Her tour itinerary for a trip London, seems she went to the Olympics and parliament.

> Like New York, there are several places called London. However, the locations that the Olympics has been held in the last 20 years is very limited. The only location that seems to fit the bill is London City in England, which she visited in 2012 and saw the summer Olympics.

Comment: @MrSethward Any feedback whether this is close?